# RxSwift: Why does flatMapLatest never execute onCompleted()?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactivex, rx-cocoa

In my Swift UIViewController, I'm attempting to subscribe to a class member of type Variable, run it through a flatMapLatest call, and then have the onCompleted() call in the flatMapLatest observable execute on all subscribers. However, while onNext() is called, onCompleted() never is and I'm not sure why.

My class member is defined as:

```
private let privateVar = Variable<String>("")
```

while in my viewDidLoad() method, I set up the observables:

```
let localVar = self.privateVar.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged()

localVar.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] sent in print("first onNext called") })
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

let mappedVar = localVar.flatMapLatest { self.ajaxLoad(var1: $0) }.share()

mappedVar.subscribe(
  onNext: { [weak self] queryRes in
    print("onNext called!")
  },
  onCompleted: { [weak self] in
    print("onCompleted called!")
  }
)
.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

and my ajaxLoad method:

```
func ajaxLoad(var1 myVar: String) -> Observable<QueryResponse> {
  return Observable.create { observable in
    apollo.fetch(query: MyQuery()) { (result, _) in
      observable.onNext(result?.data?.myQuery)
      observable.onCompleted()
    }

    return Disposables.create()
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to ReactiveX so I may be a little hazy on what the Rx lifecycle actually looks like. Why might onNext be called in the flatMapLatest call, but not onCompleted? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `flatMap` operator does not emit completed events of any observable that you return inside the block.

The following code illustrates this clearly. `.just(_)` emits the element and then a completed event, which does not terminate to subscription.

```swift
_ = Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .debug("before flatmap")
    .flatMap { .just($0 * 2) }
    .debug("after flatmap")
    .subscribe()
```

In fact, `Variable` only emits completed when deallocated. See [source v4.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/12cccb171ad9038251af6883807f0290c1d75a5b/RxSwift/Deprecated.swift#L210).
Note that Variable is deprecated in RxSwift 4, you are encouraged to use RxCocoa's similar `BehaviorRelay` instead.

```swift
deinit {
    _subject.on(.completed)
}
```

Comment: But note that an unhandled error in the inner sequence will terminate the outer sequence (`flatMap { .error(SomeError("an error")) }`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you are new and a "little hazy"...

Keep in mind that whenever `localVar` changes, it emits a new value and `ajaxLoad(var1:)` gets called. The result of `ajaxLoad(var1:)` then gets pushed to your subscribe's onNext closure.

Also keep in mind that if an Observable emits a `.completed` it's dead. It can no longer emit anything else.

So `flatMapLatest` *can't* complete (unless its source completes.) If it did, it would kill the whole pipe and no more changes to `localVar` would get routed through the pipe, `ajaxLoad(var:1)` wouldn't get called again with the new value and nothing more would get pushed to the subscribe's onNext method.

A sequence of observables can be thought of like a Rube Goldberg machine where a `completed` shuts down the machine and an `error` breaks it. The only time you should shut down the machine is if the *source* (in this case `localVar`) is finished emitting values or the *sink* (destination, in this case the onNext: closure) doesn't want any more values.